# Outlook AddIn bind RibbonCheckBox to MailItem

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I am writing an Outlook AddIn in which I read in specific MailItems.
I want to have a visual control to memorize which MailItems I already successfully read in.
For this purpose I want to use a disabled RibbonCheckBox which should save its Checked Property = true (at Application Level?!).

So far, I have no idea how to realise this the easiest and also most efficient and most comfortable way.
Maybe and I hope so, there are some Interop.Outlook functions for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a callback in the code. If you need to update any value of your control (for example, checked/unchecked) you need to call the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433552(v=office.12).aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433553(v=office.12).aspx) method of the [IRibbonUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) interface.

You can read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I have now (and like coincidence wants with the help of your tutorial https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/19/how-to-add-a-custom-property-to-the-userproperties-collection-of-an-e-mail-item-in-outlook/) added a UserProperty (with Type OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo) to the MailItem, I successfully read in. I am now searching for a way to bind my RibbonCheckBox to this UserProperty. Something like the Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange Event would be very inefficient I guess...